# JHipster is producing error while building for production

Tags: jhipster

I'm using JHipster 5.3.4. The production build producing the following error. I have cleared all the packages and re-installed them. Its still producing the error. 'dev' build works fine. It's only appearing after the upgrade to new version of JHipster, v5.3.4. I do not know what's causing the problem.

It starts by producing this error : '[ERROR] (node:9240) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use 
    new API on `.hooks` instead'.

```
[INFO] > node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js 
"--config" "webpack/webpack.prod.js" "--profile"
[ERROR] (node:9240) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use 
new API on `.hooks` instead
[ERROR] Error: Parse error on line 1:
[ERROR] (* 1.25) + 4px
[ERROR] Expecting 'SUB', 'LPAREN', 'NESTED_CALC', 'NUMBER', 'CSS_VAR', 
'LENGTH', 'ANGLE', 'TIME', 'FREQ', 'RES', 'EMS', 'EXS', 'CHS', 'REMS', 
'VHS', 'VWS', 'VMINS', 'VMAXS', 'PERCENTAGE', got 'MUL'
[ERROR]     at Parser.parseError (D:\Projects\arif\fb- 
quiz\node_modules\cssnano-preset-default\node_modules\reduce-css- 
calc\dist\parser.js:160:21)
[ERROR]     at Parser.parse (D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\cssnano- 
preset-default\node_modules\reduce-css-calc\dist\parser.js:226:22)
[ERROR]     at D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\cssnano-preset- 
default\node_modules\reduce-css-calc\dist\index.js:35:30
[ERROR]     at walk (D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\postcss-value- 
parser\lib\walk.js:15:13)
[ERROR]     at ValueParser.walk (D:\Projects\arif\fb- 
quiz\node_modules\postcss-value-parser\lib\index.js:18:5)
[ERROR]     at exports.default (D:\Projects\arif\fb- 
quiz\node_modules\cssnano-preset-default\node_modules\reduce-css- 
calc\dist\index.js:29:51)
[ERROR]     at transformValue (D:\Projects\arif\fb- 
quiz\node_modules\cssnano-preset-default\node_modules\postcss- 
calc\dist\lib\transform.js:24:45)
[ERROR]     at exports.default (D:\Projects\arif\fb- 
quiz\node_modules\cssnano-preset-default\node_modules\postcss-
calc\dist\lib\transform.js:54:100)
[ERROR]     at D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\cssnano-preset-default\node_modules\postcss-calc\dist\index.js:28:52
[ERROR]     at D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:144:26
[ERROR]     at Rule.each (D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:110:22)
[ERROR]     at Rule.walk (D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:143:21)
[ERROR]     at D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:146:32
[ERROR]     at Root.each (D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:110:22)
[ERROR]     at Root.walk (D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:143:21)
[ERROR]     at D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\cssnano-preset-default\node_modules\postcss-calc\dist\index.js:25:9
[ERROR]     at initializePlugin (D:\Projects\arif\fb-quiz\node_modules\optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin\node_modules\cssnano\dist\index.js:35:51)
[ERROR]     at <anonymous>
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[ERROR] npm ERR! errno 1
[ERROR] npm ERR! fb-quiz@0.0.0 webpack: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.prod.js" "--profile"
[ERROR] npm ERR! Failed at the fb-quiz@0.0.0 webpack script.
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[ERROR] npm ERR! errno 1
[ERROR] npm ERR! fb-quiz@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main: `npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile`
[ERROR] npm ERR! Failed at the fb-quiz@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main script.
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[ERROR] npm ERR! errno 1
[ERROR] npm ERR! fb-quiz@0.0.0 webpack:prod: `npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www`
[ERROR] npm ERR! Failed at the fb-quiz@0.0.0 webpack:prod script.
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (webpack build prod) on project fb-quiz: Failed to run task: 'npm run webpack:prod' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not pay attention to the deprecation warning, it's just a warning, the [ERROR] prefix means nothing and is due to the way maven-frontend-plugin handles output.

The real error is about CSS parsing, search for `(* 1.25) + 4px`, run [stylelint](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/cli/) or another CSS linter to detect errors. There must be something wrong in your own CSS rules or the ones you imported in your dependencies.

Comment: Ok Sir. Will inspect it